# Using union type as function parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, union-types

I have a type defined like so:

```
type FieldToAction = {
            [key in ApiActions]: ((field: Field) => void) | ((field: Field, fieldValue: FieldValue) => void)
        }
```

where `FieldValue` is a union of types:

```
type FieldValue = string | string[] | AssigneeValue | PriorityValue
```

I have a variable object where I then declare the functions set by the above types:

```
const fieldToAction: FieldToAction = {
            .
            .
            .
            "SET_DESCRIPTION": (field: Field, fieldValue: string) => field.setDescription(fieldValue),
            "SET_LABELS_VALUE": (field: Field, fieldValue: string[]) => field.setValue(fieldValue)
        };
```

This produces an error where the values in the object are not of type `FieldToAction`, I kind of understand why since I am now constraining the parameter to be a `string` or `string[]`.

My question is: Is there a way of still using the union of types' type and constraining the value in the parameter?

Thank you

Comment: Union of function is a type you don't want to end up with. It is useless. In order to make it work you need to use intersection `&` of functions instead of union `|`, which in turn produces function overloading. Try [this](https://tsplay.dev/N5Px0w). If it still don't work please provide reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using union `|` you should use intersection `&`. Intersection of functions produces a function overloading.

```js
type FieldToAction = {
    [key in ApiActions]: ((field: Field) => void) & ((field: Field, fieldValue: FieldValue) => void)
}
```

For instance, imagine you have this:

```js
type A = (a: string) => void
type B = (b: number) => void

type Union = A | B


declare const fn: Union

fn() // fn expects `never`
```

`fn` expects `never` because TS is trying to find most common type, which will conform each function in a union. To find such common type, TS intersects function arguments. It means that `fn` expects `string & number`, which in turn evaluates to `never`. See [this legendary answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type#answer-50375286).

Let's try this:

```js
type A = (a: string) => void
type B = (b: 'a') => void

type Union = A | B

declare const fn: Union

fn() // expects "a"
```

Now, `fn` expects `"a"` because it is safe to provide this to both functions.  `string & "a" === "a"`.

This is why you almost never want to end up with union of functions.